# How do I remove ASCII number 13?

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I have always wondered why I can't replace an unknown whitespace character until just an hour ago that I decided to loop through it and using php ord function I found out that it is actually character ASCII number 13. I tried the following to remove it but didn't work:

`preg_replace('/\x13/','',$string)`

any help?

Comment: Alternatively use `/\r?\n/`  - `\r` handles the carriage return equiv of `\x0D` and `\n` handles newline chars equiv of `\x0A`. This is common for windows that uses `\r\n` for line delimiters vs. *nix systems that just use `\n`

Comment: another alternative that might possibly be useful to you since you phrased it as mentioned "unknown whitespace char".. if you want to get rid of all whitespace chars that are not spaces `/(?! )\s/s` note you will need to use `s` modifier

Comment: I am still struggling. Neither of the solution works. not preg_replace('/\x0D/','',$string) not preg_replace('/\x19/','',$string)

Answer (score 2):

13 in hexadecimal is 19 in decimal, which is the ASCII control character `DC3`, which isn't properly whitespace.

You probably mean decimal 13, which is a carriage return. In hexadecimal, that's D, so you'd use `\x0D` instead.